# iPhone NavigationBar / ToolBar on Android

Tags: android

Recently, I've been working on an iphone app, and I would now like to port it to Android, for a broader distribution.
Could anybody suggest me some way to "port" (to keep those functionalities in an Android-friendly interface, perhaps) the iPhone App Navigation Bar and Toolbars?

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a blog post about [using XML layouts to build something like the iPhone UIToolbar](http://www.cannonade.net/blog.php?id=1521).

To summarise. Create a fixed height, RelativeLayout. Set up your buttons as ImageButtons in the relative layout. Use a style to define your RelativeLayout Toolbar and ImageButton toolbar buttons. Use drawables to give those toolbar elements the appropriate gradient.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When porting across mobile platforms, especially the iPhone-Android pair, don't port layouts and widgets literally. Use the most native to the targeted platform look and feel, and achieve resemblance to the original only by similar graphics, color schemes, etc. One of the most annoying things to users are the attempts to achieve full clone of the original version over the targeted one. One of the worst examples is the iPhone navigation bar, ported to Android app with the back button disabled, yuck.

Comment: Yes, that was was I meant. That is, how would you implement those features (eg, some way to navigate across activities, somewhere to place buttons, and alike) using Android UI elements?

Comment: The design of your Activities is something you should figure out, it's not a programming question but a matter of personal preference

Comment: Yes, but I'm new to Android development, and I don't know how to navigate activities yet :S (eg, the programmatic part, like push/pop viewcontroller in uinavigationcontroller, iPhone)

Comment: If you figure out first how many Activities you have and what does each of them, the way to navigate between them will come naturally. For example if you have a ListActivity with the stored contacts, and an Activity for detailed view of a single contact, then you navigate from first to second by clicking on an item from the list. You go back with the back button. If you hold on an item longer, there should be a ContextMenu with options 'edit' or 'delete'. Pressing the 'Menu' button should open an OptionsMenu and so on. Use Android for an hour to get it's feel

Answer (score 2):

Check out this presentation from Google I/O this year: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html

It specifically describes a number of UI design patterns for navigating within apps.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post, but something new arrived in Android world :

[The wonderful android UI guide](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html)

Which must be readen by every Android developpers, and every people who want to port an app from another platform to Android.

For your problem, if your are still interested in, you can read this specific part : [action bars](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)